# Trying to get property 'name' of non-object when using Mail function

Tags: php, laravel

I don't know why I get an error: "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object" when I delete `{{ $client->name }}`. It's working.
View for message:

```
   <p>
        Hello {{ $client->name }},<br />
        There's a new promotion.
    </p>
```

Controller:

```
    public function hello_client( Client $client){
    Mail::to($admin, $clients)->send(new ClientNewMessage($client));
}
```

Message:

```
class ClientNewMessage extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $client;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject('New promotion')
            ->view('emails.clientnewmessage');
    }
```

Thank you for help!

Comment: Do a `dd($client)` in your `build()` function; make sure it's not `null` (or otherwise not a `Client` model)

Comment: @TimLewis I get `Undefined variable: client`.

Comment: Oh, sorry, `dd($this->client);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you call function and write bad `$client`

```
public function hello_client( Client $client){
  Mail::to($admin, $client)->send(new ClientNewMessage($client));
}
```

and this method change for this

```
public function build()
{
  return $this->subject('New promotion')->view('emails.clientnewmessage')
  ->with('client',$this->client);
}
```

Comment: You're likely right on the `$client` vs `$clients`, but passing the data in `->with()` shouldn't be necessary; setting `public $client` _should_ be enough. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail#view-data for details.

Comment: he does not return the client object to his view that's why he gives that error

Comment: Right, but in `Mailables`, you don't explicitly have to :P As long as you set `public $client;` and then populate it in `__construct()`, like he's doing, it's available in the view via the `build()` function. If it wasn't being passed, he'd get `Undefined variable: $client`, not `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: try change public for private :v

Comment: One more question is it ok to send to multiple users like I do?
`$admin=User::role('admin')->get(); $clients=User::role('users')->get()`
`Mail::to($admin, $clients)`

Comment: if you return un array user you cant pass it

Comment: you cant try in your mail `this->admin` and pass `->with()`